# Is there a better way to reference an F# project assembly from a script?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [F#/C# - fsx Script Files and Project References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102472/f-c-fsx-script-files-and-project-references)

I have moved some F# files into a different project, and now referencing them from an F# script looks quite ugly. Here's what I had to do to reference an assembly "MyLib.dll":

// Commented out: does not work!
// #r "MyLib.dll"

// Ugly!

## r "..\MyLib\bin\Debug\MyLib.dll"

I tried to add a reference path to a project settings, but it didn't help either. Of course the assembly MyLib.dll is added to my project's referenced assemblies, but looks like FSX script files does not really care - I have to list assemblies in a script file using their absolute or relative path.

Is this by design or there is a better way?

Comment: There's the syntax ` #I @"../MyLib/bin/Debug/`  to add a path to search in, but it's only useful if you're referencing multiple code files/dlls.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the "I" directive. Still it's pity that F# script ignores referenced assemblies.

Comment: I see now it's a duplicate. There was already a question about this, with a crazy hack workaround among the answers.