# Hacking referenced assemblies

Tags: f#, assemblies

I am aware that there are already other questions on the topic, such as:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288941/the-type-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-you-must-add-a-ref)
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408015/type-reference-error-using-f-interactive)
- [This other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183960/is-there-a-better-way-to-reference-an-f-project-assembly-from-a-script)

.. but hey, I am new to F# and still don't get it.

I have a F# project (`thelibrary`) which contains some modules. This project references in the solution explorer all the necessary libraries. Each `.fs` file opens the libraries used in the module. The F# project compiles properly.

I have then another F# project which contains a script. I reference `thelibrary` and the libraries used by `thelibrary` itself. In the script I reference with `#r` the dll with `thelibrary` and all the libraries used by `thelibrary`. I then `open` all the modules.
Intellisense says all is allright until I execute the script.

The script returns the error:

```
error FS0074: The type referenced through 'Fmat.Numerics.Matrix`2' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Fmat.Numerics'.
```

What is the procedure to hack this problem? How do I proceed from there?
I am interested is a solution to this specific problem but, as well, a cookbook recipe to fix this type of issues that have been quite a source of frustration for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of F# Interactive can be a bit odd in this case. In general, I think that things work better when you use `#I` to include the path with referenced assemblies in the resolution context and then reference the libraries by name using `#r`. So if you have a library `Fmat.Numerics.dll` in a folder `C:\libs` and it references another library `another.dll` then you can do:

```
#I "C:\\libs"
#r "another.dll"
#r "Fmat.Numerics.dll`
```

The first line means that F# Interactive will automatically look in the folder with your libraries (this can be relative path to your script location too) - as a result, the next two lines can just reference the libraries by their file names.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint, but `#I` did not work either. However, after trying your suggestions, I switched back to the old code and this time the thing works. I checked with the version control and the code is exactly as it was before. I do not understand what went wrong in first place.

Comment: btw, I'd be happy to read a tutorial , if you know any, about how to troubleshoot this issues with referencing.

Comment: Also, F# Interactive occasionally gets confused when you reference different versions of assemblies - the easiest fix is to restart F# interactive (right click - restart)

Comment: Ok, thank you all. I'll keep the suggestions in mind. As I am new to F#, I found referencing a tricky thing.

Comment: I've just had the same problem and the #I fixed it!

Answer (score 5):

This is still a problem. I can also reproduce and fix the problem as follows:

I have three projects:

1. Informedica.Settings.Library
2. Informedica.Settings.Services.Interfaces
3. Informedica.Settings.Services.Models

Project 2 uses project 1 and project 3. Project 1 uses project 3.

When I load the references in the order (first proj 3 then proj 1):

```
#r @"..\..\Informedica.Settings.Services.Models\bin\Release\Informedica.Settings.Services.Models.dll"
#r @"..\..\Informedica.Settings.Library\bin\Release\Informedica.Settings.Library.dll"
```

Everything works. Unfortunately, when I use the VS2013 send references to fsi or use the new power tools generate references option, the order is:

```
#r @"..\..\Informedica.Settings.Library\bin\Release\Informedica.Settings.Library.dll"
#r @"..\..\Informedica.Settings.Services.Models\bin\Release\Informedica.Settings.Services.Models.dll"
```

This will result in the FS0074 error. Apparently, because a type from Services.Models is used in Settings.Library and the order of reference is reversed, fsi cannot handle this. Correcting the order of referencing solves the problem.

Comment: Wow, I never thought that the order with which you reference the dlls mattered! Thanks for pointing this out! This is still a problem in VS 2015 with the latest f# release (V4.0.Update2.Preview-12.18.2015).

Answer (score 2):

Running things in fsi does not add references from the project, you need to use `#r ...`.  The error message is reasonably obvious in what you need to do - add a reference to `Fmat.Numerics`.  It is also possible that you have such a reference, but that fsi is sensitive to the load order.

Comment: As per the post, everything has been referenced 1) in the solution explorer, for both projects 2) via `#r` and finally opened with `open`

Comment: Okay, so the error message is saying that this specific thing has not been referenced.  Also, `open` is irrelevant here

Comment: I have no idea where the problem could be. I have removed the reference and added it back with nuget, then done the same with the package manager console; I have also tried to shuffle the order of the #r dependencies but no luck.

Comment: I am working on a toy project, where I have trimmed all the rest and left only the piece of code that generates the issue. Thanks.