# fsx script referencing a dll referencing many dll

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, fsi

What kind of strategy do I have for the following problem.
I want to use a simple class inside a dll, which has link to various dlls, of various versions etc.

As a fsx file, my script show no error. but upon running it in fsharp interactive, it tells me

```
error FS0074: The type referenced through 'theTypeIWantToUse' 
is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'Assembly'.
```

Of course the assembly is referenced, so I imagine I need to add references to dlls it references itself.

Are there any way I could point to a compiling project's dll environment, and it recursively references the associated dlls inside the script ?

Do I have any other strategy but to do this by hand ?

**Final solution**

Tao Liu has written an add-on, if you can use it, to synchronize. It is [available here](http://apollo13cn.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/f-add-reference-addon.html)

An updated script also exists [here](https://github.com/nrolland/FStat/blob/master/FStat/scriptSetup.fsx) 
The loading still needs topological loading if one feels like doing it.

Comment: Note that the add-on is only available for Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [a script](https://gist.github.com/2062683) recently written by Gustavo Guerra, which loads all `dll` and `fs` files in `fsproj` files into F# Interactive.

The only thing you need to do is making sure that all needed `dll` files are referenced correctly in your projects.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for conditional includes, and tries to reference the file anyway. A lot of Mono references are trying to get included when they shouldn't be.