# Type classe, generic memoization

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, type-inference

Something quite odd is happening with y types and I quite dont understand if this is justified or not. I would tend to think not.

This code works fine :

```
   type DictionarySingleton private () = 
      static let mutable instance = Dictionary<string*obj, obj>()
      static member Instance = instance

   let  memoize  (f:'a -> 'b) = 
      fun (x:'a) ->
         let key = f.ToString(), (x :> obj)
         if (DictionarySingleton.Instance).ContainsKey(key) 
         then let r = (DictionarySingleton.Instance).[key]
              r :?> 'b
         else 
              let res = f x 
              (DictionarySingleton.Instance).[key] <- (res :> obj)
              res
```

And this ones complains

```
   type DictionarySingleton private () = 
      static let mutable instance = Dictionary<string*obj, _>()
      static member Instance = instance

   let  memoize  (f:'a -> 'b) = 
      fun (x:'a) ->
         let key = f.ToString(), (x :> obj)
         if (DictionarySingleton.Instance).ContainsKey(key) 
         then let r = (DictionarySingleton.Instance).[key]
              r :?> 'b
         else 
              let res = f x 
              (DictionarySingleton.Instance).[key] <- (res :> obj)
              res
```

The difference is only the underscore in the dictionary definition.
The infered types are the same, but the dynamic cast from r to type 'b exhibits an error.

**'this runtime coercition ... runtime type tests are not allowed on some types, etc..'**

Am I missing something or is it a rough edge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile in two steps, first the Type `DictionarySingleton`, then the Function `memoize` it works.
Looks like the compiler tries first to figure out the type of the underscore (which may be a generic type) and before deciding it's `obj` it also tries to infer the type of r. So at that point it is still not unified with `obj`, that's why it fails if you compile in one shot.

Comment: it might be worth submitting this to the fine fsbugs folks. thanks for checking.

Comment: excellent articles on type classes btw ... static and inline is not straight forward..

Comment: Thanks @nicolas ! It might, but I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature. I mean, sometimes type inference looks ahead to infer the type, to solve for example value restrictions, which I think is more a feature. I don't know if they can enhance the inference for these particular cases.

Comment: may be look ahead could be carried over for r as well .. ? I'll let them know, up to them to take action or not. btw I sent an enhancement suggestion related to a script you wrote originally. cf https://github.com/nrolland/AlgoInFSharpMinor/blob/master/Algo2/Algo2/Script1.fsx

Comment: Did I wrote that? Maybe it was another Gustavo ;) Anyway I can tell you I reported some bugs to fsbugs and I got always some feedback from them, I think it worth.

Comment: I think you wrote the 1st version to gather all the dependencies for a project into a file to be loaded in fsx. I extended it for solution, across projects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998144/fsx-script-referencing-a-dll-referencing-many-dll

Comment: I see now, it's Gustavo Guerra, I'm Gustavo Leon, thanks anyway :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12972/discussion-between-gustavo-and-nicolas)

Comment: As an aside - be careful with Dictionary if your code is going to be called in a threaded/parallel situation - you may get 'Key already exists' errors.  Consider ConcurrentDictionary in that case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx.  For example, Luca Bolgnese's code to replicate the Excel 'YearFrac' function fails for exactly this reason.