# DomainTypes in XmlProvider FS0039 not defined

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I am trying to use the FSharp.Data XmlProvider.
According to the samples you can access nested types and create a function that will receive a parameter of one of those types.
https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/samples/library/XmlProvider.fsx (line 177)

However when I try to do the following:

```
type businessesT = XmlProvider<"Businesses.xml">
type businessT = businessesT.DomainTypes.Business
let testfunc (b:businessesT.DomainTypes.Business) = 
    b
```

It seems to work until I actually compiles and then I get

> error FS0039: The type 'Business' is not defined

UPDATE:
The problem can be reproduced with the sample from FSharp.Data (XmlProvider.fsx)
adding a type alias after line 205

```
type Rss = XmlProvider<"http://tomasp.net/blog/rss.aspx">
type test = Rss.DomainTypes.Channel
```

What is strange is that the sample with the printDiv function is working...

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by some problem with loading the type provider - if the compiler fails to load the type provider, then it cannot run it and so none of the provided types like `Business` would be defined.

Are you using `#r` in a script file, or are you referencing the type provider through "Add References" in a project? If you're using `#r`, check if there is any error message on that line. In case of project, check other error messages output by the compiler.

I already listed [some common reasons why type provider fails to load in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343876/scripts-dont-recognize-fsharp-data).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail.
The provider is loaded. I am using Add References and I am able to read the xml using the provider. What I can't do is access the nested types under DomainTypes.

Comment: I did a quick test using an fsx file, like in the sample page but I get the same error when I try to define a function receiving a nested type. I am on VS2012 but do have VS2013 installed, not sure if it could interfere.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably the same problem as ["type provider" not recognized when building project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453911/type-provider-not-recognized-when-building-project), which has been fixed in FSharp.Data 1.1.10