# "type provider" not recognized when building project

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm using `VS 2012 Trial` and the `FSharp.Data` library for `XML` parsing. When I build the project all the type provider information turns into errors - which results in refusal to compile - like:

**Update - Output after trying to build (Framework 4.5)**

```
------ Build started: Project: temp3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe 
-o:obj\Debug\temp3.dll -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG 
--define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\temp3.XML --optimize- --tailcalls- 
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll" 
-r:C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\packages\FSharp.Data.1.1.9\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll 
-r:C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\packages\FSharp.Data.1.1.9\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll 
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" 
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" 
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" 
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll" 
-r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
--target:library --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --validate-type-providers 
--LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 
--highentropyva+ "C:\Users\Laura\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.fs" Library1.fs 
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(31,122): 
error FS0039: The type 'Transaction' is not defined
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(32,21): 
error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information 
prior to this program point. 
A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain 
the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(33,85): 
error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Postdate' is not defined
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(34,38): 
error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate 
type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding 
further type constraints
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(34,74): 
error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type 
based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type 
constraints
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(34,118): 
error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type 
based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type 
constraints
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(35,39):     
error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type 
based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type 
constraints
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(35,68): 
error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type 
based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type 
constraints
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(35,93): 
error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type 
based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type 
constraints
C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp3\temp3\Library1.fs(35,125): 
error FS0752: The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type 
based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type 
constraints
Done building project "temp3.fsproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

End update

```
The type 'Transaction' is not defined
```

and

```
Look up on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this 
program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point
to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
```

and

```
The field, constructor or member 'Postdate' is not defined
```

I have `open Fharp.Data` above my module and reference `System.Xml.Linq`.

**My Solution File:**
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74660436/temp3.zip

**My XML File:**
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74660436/KMyMoneySampleFile.xml

Sample code:

```
namespace KMyMoney
open System.IO
open System.IO.Compression
open FSharp.Data

module Read =

    let decompressFileAndRead sourceFile = (new StreamReader(new GZipStream(File.OpenRead(sourceFile), CompressionMode.Decompress))).ReadToEnd()

    type KMyMoney = XmlProvider<"KMyMoneySampleFile.xml">

    let kMyMoney (sourceData:string) = KMyMoney.Load(sourceData)

    let getAccountNames sourceData = 
        (kMyMoney sourceData).Accounts.GetAccounts()
        |> Array.map (fun acc -> acc.Id, acc.Name)
        |> Map.ofArray

    let getPayeeNames sourceData =
        (kMyMoney sourceData).Payees.GetPayees()
        |> Array.map (fun p -> p.Id, p.Name)
        |> Map.ofArray

    type TransactionNew = {Id:string; Commodity:string; Date:System.DateTime; Account:string option; Amount:float; Payee:string option
                        ; Category:string option; Number:string; Memo:string; Shares:float}

    let amount (value:string) =
        let divideArray (values:float[]) = values.[0]/values.[1]
        value.Split("/".[0]) |> Array.map float |> divideArray

    let splitTransaction (accNames:Map<string,string>) (payeeNames:Map<string,string>) (transaction:KMyMoney.DomainTypes.Transaction) =
        let split = transaction.Splits.GetSplits()
        {Id = transaction.Id; Commodity = transaction.Commodity; Date = transaction.Postdate
        ; Account = accNames.TryFind(split.[0].Account); Amount = amount split.[0].Value; Payee = payeeNames.TryFind(split.[1].Payee)
        ; Category = accNames.TryFind(split.[1].Account); Number = split.[0].Number; Memo = split.[0].Memo; Shares = amount split.[0].Shares}
```

Comment: I described some common causes of this error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343876/scripts-dont-recognize-fsharp-data - it might be one of them...

Comment: @TomasPetricek, I finally tested your three ideas. Unfortunately, none of them applied to my situation. I looked into all three and everything was working fine on my side for the issues you point out. I guess I'll have to keep trying to find a solution. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Another thing to try is to create a blank script file and use `#r` to reference the library from there. Then check if you get any error message on the `#r` line..

Comment: Another possible problem could be if the type provider DLL is located on some network share...

Comment: @TomasPetricek, It's just on my single computer. I'll try the #r and see what happens.

Comment: OK, I'm getting the same error: stdin(33,118): error FS0039: The type 'Transaction' is not defined
> 

C:\Users\Laura\BTSync\Dropbox\VisualStudio\Projects\temp\temp\MReadKMyMoney.fs(34,126): error FS0039: The type 'Transaction' is not defined

Comment: I tried this using the latest version of the XML type provider & the sample file you provided and it works fine for me - so there must be some problem with loading the type provider. Are you sure you're calling F# 3.0 compiler?

Comment: I uninstalled FSharp 2.0 hoping this would fix the problem since I read that 2.0 had problems with 1.0. I noticed That I didn't catch the first output which says warnaserror76. So I will post the entire line in my question. Not sure if I should just uninstall all versions of VS and then reinstall VS2012. Seems drastic but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: From the o/p I posted it appears I am using F# 3.0

Comment: @TomasPetricek, Would you be up for testing my test solution file? I've been trying to find a solution for this but haven't been able to find anything yet :-/ https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74660436/temp3.zip

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I was able to reproduce this, so I suppose it might be some bug in the XML provider. I'll investigate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resolution:** This issue has been fixed in FSharp.Data 1.1.10 ([nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data/1.1.10)). See comments below.

---

**Update:** I have the same issue using the following code:

```
module XmlTypeProviderIssue

open System
open FSharp.Data

type Html = XmlProvider<"""
<div>
    <span>
        <ul>
            <li/>          
        </ul>
    </span>  
</div>""">

let html = Html.GetSample()

// Div is defined
let divWorks (div:Html.DomainTypes.Div) = ()

// Span is defined
let spanWorks (span:Html.DomainTypes.Span) = ()

// Ul is not
let ulBreaks (ul:Html.DomainTypes.Ul) = ()

// and neither is Li
let liBreaks (li:Html.DomainTypes.Li) = ()
```

Essentially, DomainTypes appear in intellisense, but the compiler gives an `Error FS0039: The type 'Ul' is not defined (FS0039)` error, and the same thing for 'Li'.

---

**Original answer:**
I haven't got a proper answer for you, but interestingly, if you remove the `<TRANSACTIONS></TRANSACTIONS>` tag from your XML, it builds fine.

That is, change this:

```
<TRANSACTIONS count="2">
  <TRANSACTION postdate="2005-01-05" commodity="USD" memo="" id="T000000000000001557" entrydate="2013-07-03">
   <SPLITS>
    <SPLIT payee="P000015" reconcileflag="0" shares="-121041/100" reconciledate="" action="Withdrawal" bankid="" account="A000106" number="" value="-121041/100" memo="" id="S0001"/>
    <SPLIT payee="P000015" reconcileflag="0" shares="121041/100" reconciledate="" action="" bankid="" account="A000006" number="" value="121041/100" memo="" id="S0002"/>
   </SPLITS>
  </TRANSACTION>
  <TRANSACTION postdate="2005-01-05" commodity="USD" memo="" id="T000000000000001557" entrydate="2013-07-03">
   <SPLITS>
    <SPLIT payee="P000015" reconcileflag="0" shares="-121041/100" reconciledate="" action="Withdrawal" bankid="" account="A000106" number="" value="-121041/100" memo="" id="S0001"/>
    <SPLIT payee="P000015" reconcileflag="0" shares="121041/100" reconciledate="" action="" bankid="" account="A000006" number="" value="121041/100" memo="" id="S0002"/>
   </SPLITS>
  </TRANSACTION>
</TRANSACTIONS>
```

to this:

```
<TRANSACTION postdate="2005-01-05" commodity="USD" memo="" id="T000000000000001557" entrydate="2013-07-03">
   <SPLITS>
    <SPLIT payee="P000015" reconcileflag="0" shares="-121041/100" reconciledate="" action="Withdrawal" bankid="" account="A000106" number="" value="-121041/100" memo="" id="S0001"/>
    <SPLIT payee="P000015" reconcileflag="0" shares="121041/100" reconciledate="" action="" bankid="" account="A000006" number="" value="121041/100" memo="" id="S0002"/>
   </SPLITS>
  </TRANSACTION>
  <TRANSACTION postdate="2005-01-05" commodity="USD" memo="" id="T000000000000001557" entrydate="2013-07-03">
   <SPLITS>
    <SPLIT payee="P000015" reconcileflag="0" shares="-121041/100" reconciledate="" action="Withdrawal" bankid="" account="A000106" number="" value="-121041/100" memo="" id="S0001"/>
    <SPLIT payee="P000015" reconcileflag="0" shares="121041/100" reconciledate="" action="" bankid="" account="A000006" number="" value="121041/100" memo="" id="S0002"/>
   </SPLITS>
</TRANSACTION>
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why that caused the problem. I guess it does show that it is on the Type Provider side that has the bug. Thanks! You did get it so I could compile granted I don't know if the project will work or not if I take out the Transactions tag. I'll give you the 100 at the end of the 6 days. I'll hold on a little bit though just in case I need to award others points too. Not sure how to transfer points - I'm sure it is possible though.

Comment: I haven't had a look at the XML type provider source to see if the problem's there, but it certainly worth looking. I've managed to recreate this with a simpler XML example, so I'll get it in a clear state, post it up and maybe someone can shine some light on the issue.

Comment: @TroyKershaw If you have a simple repro, please add the link to the bug report on GitHub: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/189

Comment: @TomasPetricek [I've added a Gist](https://gist.github.com/troykershaw/6459750) to the GitHub issue above.

Comment: @Jon49 The Github issue above has a fix. I'm not sure when there will be a release on Nuget, so you might have to build from source for now.

Comment: This bugfix has been released in FSharp.Data 1.1.10 http://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data/1.1.10

Comment: Wow, you guys move fast!